# Locally compact nilpotent group has an open subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n\times K$

Tags: topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, nilpotent-groups

My question is about a possible generalization of the following structure theorem of locally compact abelian groups.

> Theorem: Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group. Then here exists a compact subgroup $K$ and a non-negative number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{R}^n\times K$ is isomorphic to an open subgroup of $G$.

I wonder whether it is possible to generalize the above for non-abelian but nilpotent groups.

The most simple case is when $G$ is nilpotent of order $3$. In this case $[G,G]$ is an abelian group, hence $[G,G]$ satisfies the Theorem. Moreover $G/[G,G]$ is always an abelian group and so satisfies the Theorem.

Can we deduce that $G$ also satisfies the theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't necessarily true for nilpotent groups. Take the Heisenberg group $$H_3(\Bbb{R})=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & a & c\\
 0 & 1 & b\\
 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}\middle|a,b,c\right\}.$$ It is a nilpotent group which is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^3$. In particular it is connected, so its only open subgroup is itself. However, it is not isomorphic as a group to $\Bbb{R}^3$ since it's not abelian.

Comment: Thanks for that!